# Looking To Update/Increase Embedded Array Objects Numeric Value

Tags: json, mongodb, nosql

I have the following item within my Mongo DB Collection

```
db.teams.insert({
    team_id: "spa2",
    date_founded: new Date("Nov 04, 1914"),
     league: "La Liga",
    points: 72,
    name: "Real Madrid",
     players: [ { p_id: "Ronaldo", goal: 135, caps: 134, age: 28 },
                { p_id: "Bale", goal: 75, caps: 45, age: 27 },
                { p_id: "Marcelo", goal: 11, caps: 25, age: 31 },
              { p_id: "Benzema", goal: 125, caps: 95, age: 22 } ]
    });
```

I want to be able to increase the number of goals scored by 3.

I have tried all morning to find a demo of this, but cant find anything near enough for me to get it to work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To increase the number you should use [$inc](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/inc/) operator. To do that for one particular document inside `players` array you should use [positional operator](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional/).

So entire operations should look like this:

```
db.teams.update({_id: ObjectId("5a48d65f3a1e3fc4b06b787f"), "players.p_id": "Ronaldo"}, {$inc: {"players.$.goal": 3}})
```

This will update only `goals` for  `Ronaldo`. If you want to update goals for all players you should use the new all positional operator [$[]](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/update/positional-all/index.html)

```
db.teams.update({_id: ObjectId("5a48d65f3a1e3fc4b06b787f")}, {$inc: {"players.$[].goal": 3}})
```